# What is the alternative of URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8") in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have to convert key value pairs into Url query parameters there is a function available in java: `URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8")`
What is the alternative of it in kotlin?

Comment: You can also use it in kotlin. Also, you can add an extension function `Map.asQueryParams()` that calls `URLEncodedUtils.format(this, "utf-8")`, for better readability.

Comment: Like hector said! > You can also use it in kotlin Kotlin is interoperable with java so its no big deal right? anyways here is an obvious example done in java simply converting it to kotlin will do the job for you ^_^.. hope it helps http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/learn-about-how-to-send-employee-information-to-the-local-se/

Comment: https://medium.com/@sudomax/getting-query-parameters-in-vert-x-v3-and-kotlin-1b8def1db566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val param = ArrayList<NameValuePair>()
```

then Add your params and just write the below code

```
object Parser {

var result = HashMap<String, String>()

fun parseJsonObject(url: String, method: String, params: List<NameValuePair>): HashMap<String, String> {
    var url = url
    var iStream: InputStream ?= null
    var data = ""

    println("url*************" + url)
    println("params*************" + params)

    var httpClient: DefaultHttpClient? = null
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method === "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            if (httpClient == null) {

                httpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
            }

            val httpPost = HttpPost(url)
            httpPost.entity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)

            // set timeout
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.params, 20000)
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.params, 30000)

            val httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)

            if (httpResponse.statusLine.statusCode === 200) {
                val httpEntity = httpResponse.entity
                iStream = httpEntity.content
                val br = BufferedReader(
                        InputStreamReader(iStream!!, "utf8"))
                val sb = StringBuffer()
                var line = ""
                while ((line == br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line)
                }
                data = sb.toString()
                br.close()
                iStream.close()
                httpClient.connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections()
                result.put("code", "200")
                result.put("value", data)
            } else {
                httpClient.connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections()
                result.put("code", "9999")
                result.put("value", "")
            }

        } else if (method === "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            if (httpClient == null) {
                httpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
            }
            val paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8")
            url += "?" + paramString
            val httpGet = HttpGet(url)

            // set timeout
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.params, 20000)
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.params, 30000)

            val httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)

            if (httpResponse.statusLine.statusCode === 200) {
                val httpEntity = httpResponse.entity
                iStream = httpEntity.content
                val br = BufferedReader(
                        InputStreamReader(iStream!!, "utf8"))
                val sb = StringBuffer()
                var line = ""
                while ((line == br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line)
                }
                data = sb.toString()
                br.close()
                iStream.close()
                httpClient.connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections()
                result.put("code", "200")
                result.put("value", data)
            } else {
                httpClient.connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections()
                result.put("code", "9999")
                result.put("value", "")
            }

        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        result.put("code", "9999")
        result.put("value", "")
        e.printStackTrace()
        return result
    }

    return result
}
```

}